# Set template does not work for homepage

Tags: xml, templates, magento, magento-1.9

I'm having a hard time declaring which template the magento homepage will use.

Unfortunately this project was not started by me, I'm just giving continuity and my knowledge about magento are very shallow.

Inside the template folder, you have the "Layout" folder with the XML related to the layout.

Within this folder, the "general" xml is named local.xml

```
<cms_index_index>
     <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/homepage.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>


    <!-- Right column ====================================================================== -->
    <reference name="left">
        <!-- Disable left sidebar blocks on home page -->
        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/compare" method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/compared" method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.compared</name></action>
        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/viewed" method="unsetChild"><name>left.reports.product.viewed</name></action>

        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/wishlist" method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist</name></action>
        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/poll" method="unsetChild"><name>right.poll</name></action>
        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/tags" method="unsetChild"><name>tags_popular</name></action>

        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/paypal" method="unsetChild"><name>paypal.partner.right.logo</name></action>

        <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
    </reference>

    <!-- Left column ====================================================================== -->
    <reference name="right">
        <!-- Disable right sidebar blocks on home page -->
        <action ifconfig="mtquartz/sidebar_blocks_home/paypal" method="unsetChild"><name>paypal.partner.right.logo</name></action>
    </reference>

</cms_index_index>
```

For some reason, this condition of cms_index_index does not take effect, it does not search the homepage.phtml, but always the 1column.phtml.

This code was already in XML, I'm trying to understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to add a page:

1) Go to **CMS -> Pages** and аdd the code like on the screen

[image]

2) Or add via module

create file by path **app\etc\modules\Homepages_PageLayouts.xml**

```
<config>
 <modules>
  <Homepages_PageLayouts>
   <codePool>local</codePool>
   <active>true</active>
  </Homepages_PageLayouts>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Создать папки и файл по таком пути app\code\local\Homepages\PageLayouts\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <global>
  <page>
   <layouts>
    <homepage_page_new>
     <label>Home 4</label>
     <template>page/homepage.phtml</template>
    </homepage_page_new>
   </layouts>
  </page>
 </global>
</config>
```

Go to **CMS -> Pages** and select this page as in the screenshot.

[image]